# What information should be given to Java WebService

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-create-restful-webservice-in-java-part-2/) to use Java Webservice for Android. This tutorial has this part in Constants.java  for database connection :

```
package com.prgguru.jersey;
//Change these parameters according to your DB
public class Constants {
    public static String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String dbName= "users";
    public static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName;
    public static String dbUser = "root";
    public static String dbPwd = "password";
}
```

I'm trying to change parameters for myself. But I don't know how to change this line :

```
public static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName;
```

How can I know what I should write for my case? Where should I look on my computer? Thanks.

Comment: That specific line depends on the database you are using. Which one do you have?

Comment: I have MySQL database,When I write **http://localhost/phpmyadmin**, I can reach MySQL database.

Comment: I mean, should I write localhost:3306 as well? or should I use a different port, if yes how can I know which port? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an SQL database (as you said in your comment to the answer) you should be able to reach it withouth changing that string but only the dbName to phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think no because I have a users database. When I use that line without changing, Tomcat doesn't reach the database.

Comment: This is the full syntax: jdbc:mysql://[IP of server]:3306/[Database Table name]. Is your table name phpmyadmin?

Comment: no it's users, so there must be something else which is wrong

Comment: Can you write your full dbUrl string here so I can check it?

Comment: I'm using exactly the same dbUrl here.